# Onclick event not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following on html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../3003_Testing/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../3003_Testing/js/search.js"></script>
<title>Search Box</title>
    <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<section class="main">
     <form class="search" >
         <input id="searchAddress" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search address" oninput="getAddress()" />
         <ul class="results" id="addressList">
         <li id="staticli"><a href="index.html">Static li element<br><span>This is a Static li element</span></a></li>
         </ul>   
     </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get write a function to handle the event when any of the list element get clicked. But it doesn't seems to be triggering at all when I click on the `<li>` element.

```
$('#addressList').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert("clicked");
    alert( $(this).text() );

});
```

The `<li>` elements are created dynamically on my `search.js` through this code:

```
listContents = $("<li id=\"" + i + "\"><a href=\"index.html\">" + addresses[i].lable + "</a></li>");
jQuery('#addressList').append(listContents);
```

And I verified through my browser's console that they are being created correctly as such

```
outerHTML: "<li id="0"><a href="index.html">6 Cashew Crescent<br><span>6 Cashew Crescent. (S)679751</span></a></li>"
```

**Let's ignore about the dynamic list first. The thing is even my static list element are not responding to the event handler upon click.** Have been trying to figure out the problem for a couple of hours now..

I have created a jsfiddle for my static li element not working https://jsfiddle.net/tmu50t9z/

jsfiddle to my whole code > https://jsfiddle.net/8wwnx64x/1/

Comment: `https://crossorigin.me/` is down, so if you are relying on this proxy (I assume you are), you are SOL.

Answer (score 1):

The script is running immediately when rendered in the head.  At that point, the DOM element referenced does not exist yet.  You can fix this by delaying the code to run until the DOM has fully loaded, or move all of your script references to the bottom of your html body.

To delay:

```
$(function() {
    $('#addressList').on('click', 'li', function() {
        alert("clicked");
        alert( $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Much better to just put the script at the bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so it doesn't delay rendering. scripts in head = anti-pattern But again, not like we need Yet Another Question and Answer on this, there has to be a valid original to close as dupe.

Comment: I agree, but it's not always trivial to move it there.

Comment: I have tried shifting my script references to just before the `</body>` and it's still responding the same way

Comment: @MaTaKazer: *"it's still responding the same way"* No, it isn't: https://jsfiddle.net/tmu50t9z/5/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm... On my side, it's still not triggering. Maybe it's due to another factor

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you take at look at the whole code https://jsfiddle.net/8wwnx64x/1/

Comment: @MaTaKazer: Your best bet is to use your debugger: [*How to debug small programs*](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -2):

Just try to put the click listener after each `<li>`has been added into the DOM or when you finish to fill the `<ul>`. Let me know if it  works to you this time.